# could not resolve property Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_wday")
@IdClass(DayPk.class)
public class Day {
    @Id
    private Date id;
..
..
}

@Embeddable
public class DayPk {
    @Column(name = "idwday")
    private Date id;
...
... other key properties
...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "t_assigned")
@IdClass(AssignedPk.class)
public class Assigned {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Day day;
...
...
}


@Embeddable
public class AssignedPk {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "t_wday_idwday", referencedColumnName = "idwday"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "t_user_iduser", referencedColumnName = "t_user_iduser")
    })
    private Day day;

...
... other key properties
...
}
```

When I try to create query

```
getSession().createQuery("FROM Day as day WHERE day.user = :user YEAR(day.id) = :year")
```

it works but when I try to create query like

```
getSession().createQuery("FROM Assigned as assig WHERE YEAR(assig.day.id) = :year")
```

I have an exception

```
could not resolve property: day.id of: com.db.entity.Assigned .....
```

but if I rename the filed id of the DayPk and the filed in the entity Day to idwday the query is works

somebody please help

Comment: It seems that it depends on `@IdClass` Annotation!

Comment: have you tried removing the @IdClass(AssignedPk.class) annotation from the Assigned entity? Even if it is not the solution, the current code is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `EmbeddedId` in your `Entity` class to access `PK` class.

```
@Embeddable
public class DayPk {
    @Column(name = "idwday")
    private Date id;
...
... other key properties
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_wday")
public class Day {
    @EmbeddedId DayPk id;
..
}


@Embeddable
public class AssignedPk {
    private Day day;

...
... other key properties
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_assigned")
@IdClass(AssignedPk.class)
public class Assigned {
        @EmbeddedId AssignedPk id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "t_wday_idwday", referencedColumnName = "idwday"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "t_user_iduser", referencedColumnName = "t_user_iduser")
    })
    private Day day;
...
...
}
```